# Optimization of N digits all permutations sum algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm

*[Note: Programming Challenge]*

**Challenge description:**

Input: List of Digits 1, 5, 6, 2, 7, 4
Non-repeated and no zeros(digits 1-9 are all valid). The goal is to create all permutations and sum them all. I used itertools permutations for this. I was able to do some test assertions with 7,8, and 9digits on my local machine. At 9 digits the time increases quite a bit to where the server times out at 12seconds, but my computer doesn't take that long. It just says to optmize my algorithm.

Below is an example of how arrays are formed, and itertools does this in each iteration of the inner loop.

```
array for the list      sum (terms of arrays)
[1]                      1 # arrays with only one term (7 different arrays)
[5]                      5
[6]                      6
[2]                      2
[7]                      7
[3]                      3
[4]                      4

[1, 5]                   6 # arrays with two terms (42 different arrays)
[1, 6]                   7
[1, 2]                   3
[1, 7]                   8
[1, 3]                   4
[1, 4]                   5

.....                   ...
[1, 5, 6]               12 # arrays with three terms(210 different arrays)
[1, 5, 2]                8 
[1, 5, 7]               13 
[1, 5, 3]                9 
........                ...
```

This is what I have so far, and it gets the job done but my main bottleneck is the sum, from 8 digits to 9 digits it increases exponentially. Below function ***passed*** two tests but on the server it times out.

```
for i in range(1, limit + 1):
        for j in permutations(digits, i):
            grandSum =+ grandSum + sum(j)
```

And below are the results from cProfile runs, 7, 8, 9:

```
13778 function calls in 0.011 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.011    0.011 <string>:1(<module>)
        7    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 GreatTotalAdditions.py:25(removefirstindex)
        1    0.006    0.006    0.011    0.011 GreatTotalAdditions.py:31(gta)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.011    0.011 {built-in method builtins.exec}
       21    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method builtins.len}
        8    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method builtins.print}
    13699    0.004    0.000    0.004    0.000 {built-in method builtins.sum}
       25    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'append' of 'list' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
        7    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'insert' of 'list' objects}
        7    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'pop' of 'list' objects}

109701 function calls in 0.086 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.085    0.085 <string>:1(<module>)
       11    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 GreatTotalAdditions.py:25(removefirstindex)
        1    0.047    0.047    0.085    0.085 GreatTotalAdditions.py:31(gta)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.086    0.086 {built-in method builtins.exec}
       27    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method builtins.len}
        9    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method builtins.print}
   109600    0.038    0.000    0.038    0.000 {built-in method builtins.sum}
       28    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'append' of 'list' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
       11    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'insert' of 'list' objects}
       11    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'pop' of 'list' objects}

986553 function calls in 0.701 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.701    0.701 <string>:1(<module>)
       16    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 GreatTotalAdditions.py:25(removefirstindex)
        1    0.374    0.374    0.701    0.701 GreatTotalAdditions.py:31(gta)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.701    0.701 {built-in method builtins.exec}
       34    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method builtins.len}
       10    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method builtins.print}
   986409    0.327    0.000    0.327    0.000 {built-in method builtins.sum}
       48    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'append' of 'list' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
       16    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'insert' of 'list' objects}
       16    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'pop' of 'list' objects}
```

**Below is where I would like some help:** 
Knowing the sum is taking most of the computation time. I came up across this math formula, example for a 3 digit number:

(3-1)! * (1 + 2 + 3) * (111)

And my implementation is below, bare in mind I'm new to python:

```
def sum_them_quick(digits):

    ones = ""
    digitsSum = 0
    # if 3 digits then form 111
    for i in range(len(digits)):
        ones += "1"

    for j in digits:
        digitsSum = digitsSum + j

    return factorial(len(digits)-1) * (digitsSum) * (int(ones))
```

However the results from this last function are wrong, and doesn't correspond with good results from passed tests. I'm not entirely sure if the number of permutations is different than itertools permutations method, but I'll confirm tomorrow for sure.

Comment: Do you have to create all the permutations, or just produce the sum?  The latter is quite simple, as each digit appears a computable number of times.

Comment: Just need to return the sum. I realize some permutations will be duplicates and thought of going that route to minimize iterations just wasn't sure.

Comment: "results ... way off" is not a problem specification.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.

Comment: `[0, 1, 3, 11, 49, 261, 1631, 11743, 95901, 876809][len(digits)] * sum(digits)`

Comment: Another example: 1562 1526 1652 1625 1256 1265 5162 5126 5612 5621 5216 5261 6152 6125 6512 6521 6215 6251 2156 2165 2516 2561 2615 2651 -> 4 digits, 4! = 24 permutations; every digit appears in every position 24/4 = 6 times, 1+5+6+2 = 14, 14*6=56, 56*1111 = 62216. Your only error seems to be that you're using (digits-1)! instead of digits!

Comment: @m69 Why are you multiplying with 1111? That's far too much.

Comment: @prune I'll be more specific on that statement. In short I gave my initial alg. 7 digits and then used the last alg. and the sum was off by more than a billion.

Comment: @StefanPochmann Because every digit appears in every position 6 times.

Comment: @m69 Huh? How do you go from 6 to 1111?

Comment: @StefanPochmann It appears 6 times as ###d, 6 times as ##d#, 6 times as #d## and 6 times as d###. So you multiply it by 6*1, 6*10, 6*100 and 6*1000.

Comment: @m69 Sorry, doesn't make sense to me. And your result 62216 is much larger than the correct result 686 (as computed by OP's correct solution and my above solution). And you'd be even further off if you hadn't made your 14*6=56 error.

Comment: https://youtu.be/PQ5OySVcvSQ This video explains the latter method I've used.

Comment: @m69 Why 18 now? And why add 4-digit integers? That's not what the OP's correct code is doing.

Comment: @kodaman Where is this problem from? Can you link to it? You seem to be confused about what the problem is, so I'd like to read the original description.

Comment: @kodaman And is my above solution correct?

Comment: @StefanPochmann Sorry, I'm doing something else at the same time. 6*14 = 84, 84 * 1111 = 93324; If you add all the integers in my example in the comment, you indeed get 93324. That's what I understand from the question; but it's somewhat confusingly explained.

Comment: @m69 What about all the shorter permutations?

Comment: @StefanPochman I'm not confused about the problem at all. I've managed to pass two unit tests. However other unit test timeout, suggesting my algorithm is slow. My main problem is optimization using mathematics, that's where I'm confused about which method to use. Challenge is here https://www.codewars.com/kata/great-total-additions-of-all-possible-arrays-from-a-list

Comment: So it's the sum of all 1,2,3...k-subset permutations?

Comment: @kodaman If you're not confused about the problem, then why are you describing two different problems and act like they're the same?

Comment: Just ran the method and 1562 give the result of 93324.

Comment: @StefanPochman I'll reword question and divide it into challenge description and my problem.

Comment: The problem remains. Your second approach (and the video) is for a different problem, not for the one you're actually trying to solve. I just solved that kata, btw.

Comment: That was quick. Don't spoil it then. I think you just gave me good info on your last comment. Could you answer on how the video algorithm and the kata are different problems? Or would that give it away?

Comment: @m69 Yes, as the example analysis and the OP's correct code show (use `limit = len(digits)`, which they forgot to mention).

Comment: @kodaman Well I already "spoiled" it with the solution in my first comment (which I btw used verbatim in my solution that got accepted). Your second approach is for the problem where a permutation like (4,1,3,2) is interpreted as the number **4132**, whereas your actual job is to just sum the digits, i.e., 4+1+3+2 = **10**.

Comment: So I saw your first comment and it doesn't make sense how you completed the challenge. I figured out how to actually get the answer. sum of digits * len(digits) - 1 * multiplier. The multiplier is where I'm trying to figure out how to calculate. The multiplier changes based on how many digits at least when it gets to the 3 numbers per permutation. For the 2 numbers is 2. For the 3 number permutation is 15 for 7 digits, and 18 for 8 digits.